# send email message action is not sending email

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am creating a form through web form from marketers and on submit button's save action I have added a 'Send Email Action' for sending a email. And I have also changed 'Send Email Message' action's parameters  and . But still it is not sending email. Please tell me how to resolve this problem?

here is the error:

```
We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request.
```

Comment: Can you check for the full stack trace in the log files? Is SMTP server defined properly in your config files?

Comment: plz tell me entries in config file for this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you should check.

1. Does the SMTP server you have configured, actually pass mail through?
2. Are there any exceptions showing in the Sitecore logs?

This blog post: http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2012/05/email-confusion-configuring-smtp.html takes you through pretty much everything in relation to setting SMTP options for your Sitecore solution and for Webforms for Marketers. It's easy to get confused as to how these work.